# Questions about a general term and a number of terms in a finite sum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, induction

The inequality below occurs in a proof of convergence of $p$-series for an exponent greater than $1$.

Statement:

> Use induction to show $\displaystyle{1 + \frac{1}{2^r} + \frac{1}{3^r} + \frac{1}{4^r} + \ldots + \frac{1}{(2^n - 1)^r} \le \frac{1 - \left(\frac 12\right)^{(r - 1)n}}{1 - \left(\frac 12\right)^{r - 1}}}, \ r \ne 1$

I'll only post a part of the proof for brevity.

Proof:

> The inequality holds for $n = 1$. Assume the inequality is true in the case $n = k - 1$ as well. So,

> $\displaystyle{1 + \frac{1}{2^r} + \frac{1}{3^r} + \ldots + \frac{1}{(2^k - 1)^r} \\ = \left(1 + \frac{1}{2^r} + \frac{1}{3^r} + \ldots + \frac{1}{(2^{k - 1} - 1)^r}\right) \\ + \underbrace{\left(\color{blue}{\frac{1}{(2^{k - 1})^r}} + \color{blue}{\frac{1}{(2^{k - 1} + 1)^r}} + \ldots \frac{1}{(2^k - 1)^r}\right)}_{2^{k - 1} \text{ terms each }\le \frac{1}{\left(2^{k - 1}\right)^r}} \le \ldots}$

My questions:

1. How did they find the general terms in blue above? Does the sequence continue with $\displaystyle{\ldots, \frac{1}{(2^{k - 1} + 2)^r}, \frac{1}{(2^{k - 1} + 3)^r}, \frac{1}{(2^{k - 1} + 4)^r}, \ldots, \frac{1}{(2^k - 1)^r}}$? Not obvious to me.
2. How do they know there are $2^{k - 1}$ terms in the second pair of brackets?

Comment: 1) you have that correct
$$-$$ 2)  You need $2^k$ terms in total and you already have $2^{k-1}$ terms, $2^k - 2^{k-1} = 2^{k-1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it looks funny, but this is just basic counting/indexing.

1. Let's focus on the term $1\over(2^{k-1}-1)^r$ and ask the question: "what comes next?" Since the sum is increasing the base of the exponent by 1 with each term, then the next few terms should be:

$$
{1\over(2^{k-1})^r}
+
{1\over(2^{k-1}+1)^r}
+
{1\over(2^{k-1}+2)^r}
+
{1\over(2^{k-1}+3)^r}
+
\cdots
$$

2. Since the last term in the sum is $1\over(2^{k}-1)^r$, we now need to know how many terms are in our sum above, up to this term. This is just the difference between the first and last index +1, so:

$$
(2^k-1)-(2^{k-1})+1=2^k-2^{k-1}=2^{k-1}(2-1)=2^{k-1}
$$